# When drawable left is set the floating text is moving towards right

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-drawable, android-textinputlayout

I have an `EditText` with `TextInputLayout`. I am setting an image at drawable left, but when I set it the floating hint text also moving towards right. Please see the below screenshot:

[image]

I want the view looks like below:

[image]

If anybody has idea on how to fix it, please help me.

Xml code below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_cardnum"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/cardnumEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/darkGray"
                android:maxLength="255"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:hint="@string/cardNum" 
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/card_generic"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: so what you want ?

Comment: I want the label should be aligned to left, ie inline with the drawable. Now the label is coming after the drwable.

Comment: @Aju did you manage to find a solution to this problem? If so please do share it with us.

Comment: @ShafayatMamun not yet....

Comment: Try using paddingLeft="10dp"

Comment: I want to do like this. Did you find out solution? @Aju

Comment: I found solution in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39530520/adding-a-drawableleft-to-an-edittext-shifts-the-hint-towards-right-if-edittext[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39530520/adding-a-drawableleft-to-an-edittext-shifts-the-hint-towards-right-if-edittext)