# Adding a drawableLeft to an EditText shifts the hint towards right, if edittext is inside TextInputlayout

Tags: android

[image]I have make an EditText inside TextInputLayout. I am setting a drawableLeft to an EditText at runtime in my code, but as soon as I add the drawableLeft the floating hint inside TextInputLayout shifts to right leaving the space equal to drawable width. But I dont want that space in hint, so help me to resolve this!!

Comment: please post your xml

Comment: Use _setCompoundDrawablePadding_

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`TextInputLayout` uses a library-restricted helper class – `CollapsingTextHelper` – to manipulate its hint text. The instance of this helper is private, and none of the attributes associated with its layout are exposed, so we'll need to use a little reflection to get access to it. Furthermore, its properties are set and recalculated every time the `TextInputLayout` is laid out, so it makes sense to subclass `TextInputLayout`, override its `onLayout()` method, and make our adjustments there.

```kotlin
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Rect
import android.util.AttributeSet
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

class CustomTextInputLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = com.google.android.material.R.attr.textInputStyle
) : TextInputLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val collapsingTextHelper = try {
        TextInputLayout::class.java.getDeclaredField("collapsingTextHelper")
            .apply { isAccessible = true }.get(this)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        null
    }

    private val recalculateMethod = collapsingTextHelper?.let { helper ->
        try {
            helper.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod("recalculate")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            null
        }
    }

    private val collapsedBounds = collapsingTextHelper?.let { helper ->
        try {
            helper.javaClass.getDeclaredField("collapsedBounds")
                .apply { isAccessible = true }.get(helper) as Rect
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            null
        }
    }

    override fun onLayout(
        changed: Boolean,
        left: Int,
        top: Int,
        right: Int,
        bottom: Int
    ) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom)

        val edit = editText ?: return
        val helper = collapsingTextHelper ?: return
        val recalculate = recalculateMethod ?: return
        val bounds = collapsedBounds ?: return

        bounds.left = edit.left + edit.paddingLeft
        try {
            recalculate.invoke(helper)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // fail silently
        }
    }
}
```

The custom class is a drop-in replacement for the regular `TextInputLayout`. For example:

```xml
<com.example.app.CustomTextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Model (Example i10, Swift, etc.)"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/bmw"
        android:text="M Series" />

</com.example.app.CustomTextInputLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot showing the adjusted hint alignment.]

Comment: add these lines to the proguard rules so that it will still work on your production build: `-keep class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout{ *; }`
`-keep class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingTextHelper{ *; }`

Comment: This latest version doesn't seem to require any special ProGuard rules, but I'm not sure why; e.g., maybe something else is already keeping those classes and members, or maybe something changed in the build tools, etc. If anyone runs into any issues, please leave a comment.

Comment: If there are any problems with the reflection or ProGuard or whatever, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45511397) shows a slightly different approach that puts the custom class in the library package, therefore giving it direct access to the relevant field and method. You might get a library restriction error, but it can be suppressed. Aside from that, the only downside might be that Material Components' `TextInputLayout` figures the bounds differently 'cause of all its new bells and whistles, so things might not line up correctly with just the basic padding calculations shown there.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Its a common problem that I faced recently.I solved it with simple one line code:
Place a padding between your hint and `drawbleleft` by using `drawble padding`.
If you are adding drawble at runtime simply add `drawblepadding` in xml before hand or you can dynamically add drawble padding.

Answer (score -2):

```
 editText.setCompoundDrawablePadding(your padding value);
```

Try it and let me know. It worked for me.