# TextInputLayout with drawable move hint

Tags: android, android-layout, android-textinputlayout, textinputlayout

I added left drawable to TextInputLayout and now hint moves to right. It should be at start of row.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/edit_layout_currency"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edit_layout_date_of_birth"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:errorEnabled="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_text_currency"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:hint="@string/registration_currency"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/color_edit_text"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I've a solution for that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39530520/adding-a-drawableleft-to-an-edittext-shifts-the-hint-towards-right-if-edittext.

Comment: Thanks!!! Maybe it can be duplicated