# Move Text Input Layout floating text to desired position

Tags: android, xml, android-textinputlayout

I have an `editext` with two images one in left side and one in right side, these three views(edittext and both images should appear in a white background) and when user click on editext, its text should move to top-left corner, means just above the left image.
What i tried is this:

```
  <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dim_7">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/dim_45"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/rounded_solid_white" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imgName"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/dim_21"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/dim_21"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dim_10"
                            android:src="@drawable/name" />

                        <com.investorapp.others.custom_view.MyTextInputLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                            <com.investorapp.others.custom_view.MyEditTextRegular
                                android:id="@+id/etLogInEmailId"
                                style="@style/MyEditTextStyle"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dim_10"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:hint="Enter Email Address"
                                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dim_10"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dim_15"
                                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dim_40"
                                android:paddingRight="@dimen/dim_10"
                                android:paddingTop="@dimen/dim_20" />
                        </com.investorapp.others.custom_view.MyTextInputLayout>

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imgValidEmail"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/dim_21"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/dim_21"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dim_10" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>


            </RelativeLayout>
```

my output of above code is like this image [image]

But that's not what i want. My expected output is this:
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated. If there is any library available that would also helpful.

Comment: you will have to implement your own styles or give some margins or padding to the hint.

Comment: I tried everything with padding and margin by edittext's text move to 90 degree

Comment: did you tried using styles ?

Comment: No, i did'nt find any useful styles to work in that,if you have some please put in answer

Comment: It looks like you could simplify that setup quite a bit by setting the `rounded_solid_white` background directly on the `EditText`, and using the images as its compound drawables - i.e., `drawableLeft`, `drawableRight`, etc. - instead of the separate `ImageView`s. Then [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39568320) shows how you can align the floating hint all the way to the left, over that drawable. If you can't change your setup, for whatever reason, that answer should at least give you some ideas as to how to move that hint a bit.

Comment: take a look at this answer. it will give you the idea how to do it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609710/textinputlayout-how-to-give-padding-or-margin-to-hint

And also mike's comment will surely help you

Comment: Thanks Mike you solution work for me, Thanks Umair for replying