# om.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout floating above left drawable of an EditText

Tags: android, material-design

Is there any way  to make the TextInputLayout floating label to show above the left drawable of an EditText. i have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39568320/9030938) ,this is working fine for support.design.widget.TextInputEditText but now working for com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

```
     <com.example.hb.drawsample.CustomTextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
        android:hint="test">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </com.example.hb.drawsample.CustomTextInputLayout>
```

here is my CustomTextInputLayout class

```
package com.example.hb.drawsample;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class CustomTextInputLayout extends TextInputLayout {
    private Object collapsingTextHelper;
    private Rect bounds;
    private Method recalculateMethod;

    public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        init();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

        adjustBounds();
    }

    private void init() {
        try {
            Field cthField = TextInputLayout.class.getDeclaredField("mCollapsingTextHelper");
            cthField.setAccessible(true);
            collapsingTextHelper = cthField.get(this);

            Field boundsField = collapsingTextHelper.getClass().getDeclaredField("mCollapsedBounds");
            boundsField.setAccessible(true);
            bounds = (Rect) boundsField.get(collapsingTextHelper);

            recalculateMethod = collapsingTextHelper.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("recalculate");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            collapsingTextHelper = null;
            bounds = null;
            recalculateMethod = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void adjustBounds() {
        if (collapsingTextHelper == null) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            bounds.left = getEditText().getLeft() + getEditText().getPaddingLeft();
            recalculateMethod.invoke(collapsingTextHelper);
        }
        catch (InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried other answer too from but not getting any solution

Comment: I personally tested that answer with `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout` when I added the notes there on November 29 of this year. It works just fine.

Comment: Please read the notes on the answer there. The field names changed. You're still using the old ones.

Comment: @MikeM. i have updated my question please check

Comment: I have added a comment above. Please check that.