# TextInputEditText drawable padding without hint

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-edittext, android-custom-view

I am using a textInputEditText and I would like to add a drawable without affect on hint. 
[image]

when I add the drawable the hint has a padding effect.

here is the code:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">  

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/cell"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_local_phone_black_24dp"
                    android:hint="@string/cell"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@{personalInfo.phone ?? `-`}"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray_4d"
                    tools:hint="@string/cell"
                    tools:text="362-43-23-5-3" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: You can use only EditText without TextInputLayout. OR set `app:hintEnabled="false"` to TextInputLayout.

Comment: Have you tried `android:drawableStart`?

Comment: I think this is the answer you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39568320/8969466

Comment: @PriyaSindkar this link is useful but I will let the question if there is another way or with attributes. 
and the question for TextInputLayout not editText, may be there is an attribute or another trick for TextInputLayout.
Thanks!

Comment: `TextInputLayout` is what's drawing that hint, not the `EditText`, so that's what needs to be modified. Also, there are no attributes to directly set the floating hint position, which is why you need to manipulate its bounds.