# Adding a drawableLeft to an EditText shifts the hint towards right, if edittext is inside TextInputlayout. when the proguard is enabled

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

This is a duplicate of: [Adding a drawableLeft to an EditText shifts the hint towards right, if edittext is inside TextInputlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39530520/adding-a-drawableleft-to-an-edittext-shifts-the-hint-towards-right-if-edittext)

i have followed the accepted answer, it is working fine in the debug mode whereas in the release mode with proguard enabled hint text is shifted towards right.

```
-keep class com.google.android.material.** {*;}
```

i added this and it started working as expected

Comment: The answer uses reflection, so my guess is that those methods are removed by proguard, triggering a caught exception. Try adding the methods used to your proguard file with `-keep` option.

Comment: show your proguard